# Improvement for a lightweight and rapid object interaction using Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I have a question about the interaction of objects with each other.
Especially with regard to the application on Hololens 2 and the computing power that comes with it.

#### What would I like to do:

I have two objects. One is a simple staff and is moved by the player / user of HoloLens 2. The other object is a complex construct into which the staff shall be inserted.

#### Current behaviour:

After adding a BoxCollider and Rigidbody component to the staff and a MeshCollider to the complex object, I was able to create some interaction. Unfortunately the whole process is so expensive that it causes the HoloLens to crash.

#### My question:

- Since I don't need any physics, but only pure non-penetrable objects, does anybody have a hint how I can achieve better performance?
- Or what I have to change completely to make it as fast and lightweight as possible?

#### Notes:

- Most entries online that I have found related to firing events or triggers that I do not need at all.
- Even in PlayMode on the local computer it stutters.
- Due to the complexity of the mesh I cannot simplify the target object.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Did you try to optimizing it from the data you get from the Unity's ```Profiler```?

Comment: I looked at the profiler, and most of the CPU usage comes from the physics stack. The optimization would be to get rid of the physics, and that's what I'm trying to do. If you have a tip on how to do this, I'd be grateful to hear it.

Comment: Are you using ```Phycs.Raycast()```. if yes, and you are doing it on each and every frame. please try to reduce that number of times you ```Phycs.Raycast()```.

Comment: can you sand me the picture of the, "complex Object". I can have an idea how you can optimize that in terms of collider.

Comment: @Ankit: I don't use `Raycast()` myself, but there are some calls from the MRTK site which I have not checked all, because I don't know if it would be good to change them.
As a model i have created a model similar to this [one](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-3d-ball-cartography-center-communication-complex-earth-triangle-topography-18318531.html) for the time being, only a little more finer splitted

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply. Can you use just a sphere collider.

Comment: because sphere collider's mesh has less vertices. so it would be easy for your CPU co calculate.

Comment: And please do check Profiler Tool when it comes to optimizing your game in Unity. it's a very helpful tool built by Unity.

Comment: I should be sorry, because I'm the one who answered late and I'm the one with the question. The idea with the SphereCollider is unfortunately not applicable, because I have to collide with the struts, because I want to navigate another object into the mesh.
I used the profiler. The heaviest processes are Physics.Processing and Context.contactManagerDiscreteUpdate with about 25 ms each and the Gfx.ProcessCommands (probably resulting from the physical interaction), which is likely responsible for updating the meshes.

Comment: ok, Go to ```profiler > physics``` and look at all the processes and take a look at the time taken to complete you can get some idea what happening.

Comment: well i get the following parameters:
active dynamics: 1 -> the object that is moved, so that should be fine
active kinematics: 1 -> the object which shall be moved and has the rigidbody attached
static colliders: 5 -> all objects UI-elements which do not have a rigidbody attached
rigidbody: 1 -> corresponds to active kinematics 
contacts: 1 or 2 -> the number of contacts between two objects
there is nothing particular standing out or am i missing something?

Comment: Can you share me the screenshot of the profiller's physics section?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, currently I will go with the solution approach of Will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always decimate the complex object in something like blender: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html

Import the decimated object into unity then use that mesh for the mesh collider instead of the rendered mesh.

That should allow you to simplify the mesh so it's more performant but still be plenty complex enough to closely follow the geometry of the original model.

I've used a similar method to reduce improve shadow rendering performance quite effectively.

Comment: For now, this approach works pretty well, which is why I accept it as an answer.
Didn't even think of that, so thank you very much.
In the future, however, i will probably have to deal with this topic again.